# Correlation Test NOT giving the same results when run in different ways?

Tags: r

On paper, the following codes should give similar results, but why doesn't it?

[image: picture]

Comment: Why don't you just copy and paste what's in the picture into your question, preferrably wrapping it inside backticks so it is formatted as code?

Answer (score 1):

`cor.test` has two interfaces. One where you specify two vectors and the other where you specify `formula` and `data`. Only the second interface offers `subset`:

```
cor.test(~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Width, data = iris, subset = Species == "setosa")
```

It is a frequent source of error and thus I avoid `subset` in functions.